# Failed to open stream: No such file of directory in... PHP fopen

Tags: php, file, cookies, directory, fopen

this is my code

```
include 'connection.php';
setcookie('username',$name,time()+86400,"/");
echo $_COOKIE['username'];
$my_file = '/../../users/'.$name."/index.php";
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
```

when the code runs I want it to create a file with the directory `/../../users/[username]` where `[username]` is stored in the `$name` variable. When I run my code it just gives me a lousy error and it doesn't run any code after line 6 from above.

It won't create the file and the error is...

> Warning: fopen(/../../users/codemaster7/index.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c02/h10/mnt/45563/domains/pizzascripters.com/html/projects/nik/Champion/register/index.php on line 107
>   Cannot open file: /../../users/codemaster7/index.php

Does anyone have an idea on whats going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1 include 'connection.php';
2 setcookie('username',$name,time()+86400,"/");
3 echo $_COOKIE['username'];
4 $my_file = 'index.php';
5 $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$my_file);
```

I update the directory of file to just a file name in line 4. if you wanna use the directory as a parameter then use the function file($myfile); which return the array of data from your file.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code so that it was only creating a file and not a directory. The code works great!

Answer (score 2):

fopen can only create a file at the specified path but it cannot create any directories. You will have to use something like [mkdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) to create a new directory before you call fopen.

Answer (score 0):

> This error often occurs when you miss or misspell something like here I did it first

```
$path = Yii::getAlias('@common') .'/upload/images/'. $model
```

Here the spell is ***upload*** but it should be ***uploads*** as in my project it is ***uploads***. the wrong spell gave me this error. so this often occurs when the path is unknown

```
$path = Yii::getAlias('@common') .'/uploads/images/'. $model
```